# Deploy Express app with Typescript on Azure

Tags: typescript, azure, express, deployment, build

I'm trying to deploy an Express server on Typescript on Azure following this tutorial :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-nodejs?tabs=windows&pivots=development-environment-vscode

It's a dummy app with a simple Hello World in an index.ts file. However I face a lot of issues.

This is the message I get browsing the website :
"You do not have permission to view this directory or page."

When I try to check inside my deployed folder, here is what I get
[image]

So no web.config file. However the "SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT" parameter is set to true and should generate it.

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "test-azure-3",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "tslint -c tslint.json -p tsconfig.json --fix",
    "build": "tsc",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "node .",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.14",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "typescript": "^4.5.5"
  }
}
```

And my settings in Azure :

[image]

[image]

(A bit surprised to see .Net as stack)

Feel free to ask any more info !

EDIT : As mentionned by Felipe, I also created a specific Azure project for the dist folder but I still have the same behaviour

[image]

Comment: Since this is a Typescript project you're supposed to build it to get it promoted. That would generate a index.js file which would be the startup of your application. You shouldn't run ts files in production. run "nom run build" and get those files generated (usually on "dist" folder and test then running "node index.js" to see how that goes.

Comment: I already built it and indeed get the index.js file, but I was expected the web.config file to be generated and target the dist folder. I also tried to deploy the index.js file but I had the same result

Comment: web.config file is something specifically to the IIS. Node doesn't have anything to do with it. You will have to build this web.config your self to get this running on IIS. Actually you should deploy only the content off your dist folder. I see on the screenshot that you sent all the files of your project.

Comment: If you're running a node app on azure, you probably should have to deploy dist folder's content, set the environment variables and that should do it.

Comment: I edited my post with the dist folder deployement
What do you mean by "set the environment variables" ?

Comment: I meant 'Application Settings'. Those get converted to environment variables that you would call on node express. E.g. process.env.MY_VARIABLE_NAME

Comment: I only have "const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;", are there any other required ?
Does the process.env.PORT have to be define somewhere in Azure ?

Comment: PORT variable tells node in which port is supposed to run it. if you want your system running on port 3000 then you should set PORT = 3000 on the application settings. I would guess that Azure expected your software running on port 80 instead.

Comment: Same think putting PORT=80 on application settings ( I would expect azure to manage it by default as it's classic on node apps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I found a solution, that will probably not please the ones in trouble.

What worked for me was to leave Azure to go to Heroku, which first worked in a few minutes but also is easier to use (for me at least).

There is a good tutorial that I found :
https://medium.com/developer-rants/deploying-typescript-node-js-applications-to-heroku-81dd75424ce0

Answer (score 0):

Azure app service will pull down a zip file if there is one. You have to zip your dist folder in the pipeline and then use that repo as source for app service. If you are using azure repos it's fairly straightforward. Add this to your pipeline config file:

```
 - script: |
     npm run build
   displayName: 'npm build'
   
 - task: ArchiveFiles@2
   inputs:
     rootFolderOrFile: 'dist'
     includeRootFolder: true
     archiveType: 'zip'
     archiveFile: 'dist.zip'
     replaceExistingArchive: true
```

Your start script in package.json should look like this:

```
"start":"node dist/index.js"
```

Also azure app service is using docker containers and they expose port 8080 so your app should be running on 8080.

Answer (score -1):

Going through all that we discussed:

1. web config is related to the IIS only. NodeJS has nothing to do with it;
2. you should run "npm run build" and publish the files in the "dist" folder only. That will generate an index.js file in the root and that file is what node will be looking in order to run your application. .ts files should not be executed on production environment;
3. Add the environment variables necessary to the "Application Settings" on Azure. That will populate the variables that your app need to run.
4. You probably should set the variable PORT to 80 because Azure is possibly expecting to run your app on port 80;

Comment: 1. I tested with an ExpressJs app (with javascript instead of typescript) and it works. There a web.config file is generated. Also, the azure tutorial recommends to have some.
2. How to tell to Azure to deploy the dist folder only ? In my package.json ? Azure config ?
3. Which environment variables are required in Azure app settings ? I have 3 (in my second screenshot)
4. I also tried to update the port in Azure variable to 80, it doesn't work

Do you have any other ideas ? Is relly express typescript compatible with Azure ?

Comment: 2. you should promote only diet folder to Azure otherwise you'd be exposing your source code. 3. only the ones you app require. I guess that'd be PORT and NODE_ENV. I don't think that .NET is the platform you're looking for if you're deploying a node app. Select NodeJS instead; 4. Node is indeed compatible with Azure BUT you have to understand that typescript is an intermediate language to javascript (which is what NodeJS runs over express). So no typescript code should be ever sent to production environment. Also packages.json is meant for development environment only.

Comment: I followed all this steps and still it doesn't work, was you able to reproduce an Express Typescript "Hello World" app and succefully deploy it to Azure ?

Comment: I will be able to help if you tell me what doesn't work mean in this case. Can you post the error you're getting and the structure of those files on azure after the discussion we have about how to deploy those?